# Does R' = R*R'*R^(-1) hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, orthonormal

Given two 3D rotation matrices ($3\times 3$) $R$ and $R'$, does this equivalence hold?:

$R' = R*R'*R^{-1}$

My intuition tells me so, but I can't find a formal proof for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Rotations around different axes do not commute.  So, generally speaking, $R_{a} \neq R_{b} R_{a} R_{b}^{-1}$ unless the two rotations have a common axis of rotation.

Comment: Interesting remark. That's why then this holds with 2D rotation matrices, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R' = RR'R^{-1}$ holds, then $R'R = RR'$. So you are basically asking if 3D rotation matrices commute. The answer would have been yes for 2D, but for 3D the answer is no.

Consider $R = R_x(\tfrac{\pi}{2}) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $R' = R_z(\tfrac{\pi}{2}) = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

We have $R_x(\tfrac{\pi}{2})R_z(\tfrac{\pi}{2}) = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ but $R_z(\tfrac{\pi}{2})R_x(\tfrac{\pi}{2}) = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

What does $R'$ denote? If, as other answerers have supposed, it is just some other rotation matrix, then the answer is, as they have noted, no.

If you mean "$R$ transpose", then, as before, this is

$$
RR^T \stackrel{?}{=} R^TR
$$

which is asking whether it is **normal** or not. In this case, rotations are normal, so the answer is yes.

Comment: R' is just some other rotation matrix, yes. Sorry, I forgot that R' usually denotes the transpose of R...

Comment: I wouldn't say "usually", merely "sometimes". ;) Anyway, I suspected that they were probably unrelated, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you wrote is equivalent to $R' R = R R'$.  Do all 3-D rotations commute?